# Jtextfield add automatically commas every 3 digits

Tags: java, jtextfield

Regards, I'm trying to make a jtextfield that once typed a number, it automatically add commas every 3 digits like this, User type 3000000 & jtextfield show this: 3.000.000

this what i had tryed but no works.

```
JFormattedTextField nameOfTextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
                textField_10 = new JFormattedTextField(nameOfTextField);
                textField_10.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
                        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
                        if(Character.isLetter(c) && !evt.isAltDown()){
                            evt.consume();

                        }
                    }
                });

                textField_10.setColumns(10);
                textField_10.setBounds(289, 133, 83, 20);
                panel_6.add(textField_10);
```

Comment: That KeyListener should not be necessary.  But you cannot create a JFormattedTextField from another JFormattedTextField.  `new JFormattedTextField(nameOfTextField)` will not compile.  I’m not sure what you’re trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: so , how could be?

Answer (score 0):

JFormattedTextField already does this.  You don’t need to do anything special.  You don’t even need a KeyListener.  This is sufficient:

```
JFormattedTextField nameOfTextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
//textField_10 = new JFormattedTextField(nameOfTextField);      // This will not compile.  There is no such constructor.
textField_10 = nameOfTextField;

textField_10.setColumns(10);
```